# What is bash's meta key?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I tried to use `xmodmap` to map <kbd>META_L</kbd> to the <kbd>MENU</kbd> key but it doesn't seem to be accepted by `bash` as the meta key. So, I am wondering how these components (keyboard, X, xterm, bash) relate to each in regard the the Meta- and Super-Keys. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Let me put this another way. The bash man page says, for example, that the function yank-nth-arg is bound to <kbd>M-C-y</kbd> and it works when I press <kbd>Esc-Control-y</kbd>. But I find this a bit cumbersome. So how can I make bash accept another key as <kbd>Meta</kbd> (like the <kbd>Menu</kbd>) for all its default bindings?

Comment: Is your `MENU` key even noticed by X? What window manager are you using - some of them can help you redefining your keys.

Answer (score 17):

The mapping from keyboard keys to modifiers like `Meta` and `Control` is handled by the X server (i.e. the low-level part of the GUI). This mapping can be manipulated through the old-style [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xmodmap.1.xhtml) command or the new-style [XKB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_keyboard_extension) interface, or through a GUI configuration tools that uses one of these under the hood.

By default, on most setups, the `Meta` key is the key labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd>. This is because historically, many unix workstations had a key labeled <kbd>Meta</kbd> where PCs have a key labeled <kbd>Alt</kbd>. So if you have a binding for `M-C-y`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>.

To check what your current bindings are, start the `xev` program in a terminal. With the xev window focused, press keys; you'll see a transcript of the generated events in the terminal.

The communication between terminal emulators (or terminal devices corresponding to a physical terminals) and applications uses characters. When you press <kbd>A</kbd>, the terminal receives the information “`A` key, no modifier”, but what it sends to the application running in the terminal is the character `a`. When you press a function key like <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>, there's no corresponding character; the terminal sends a character sequence beginning with the escape character (byte 27, sometimes written `\e` or `^[`). When a terminal emulator such as xterm received a key press event with the `Meta` modifier, it translates that key to an escape character followed by the key's underlying function, e.g. `\ea` (escape, lowercase a) when you press <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

[What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con/4132#4132) may be useful background.

Answer (score 5):

The key event is generated by the X server (as configured by `xmodmap`), and is sent to your X application.  Your window manager could intercept this before it is sent to xterm.  XTerm, in turn, translates the event to some bytes and sends the bytes to the pseudo-tty allocated by your shell, bash.

Please note that not all events are translated directly to bytes by XTerm.  For instance, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> keys, by themselves, generate X keyboard events, but XTerm sends *nothing* to the shell (or other application) running within it.  This also includes the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key by itself, but not the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key.  However, the event generated by pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> will make XTerm send either the byte 0xE5 or the two-byte sequence 0x1B 0x65, depending on the XTerm.VT100.metaSendsEscape resource setting.

Answer (score 5):

Bash's *meta key* originally was defined like this ([`lib/readline/ChangeLog`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/ChangeLog)):

```
Mon Jul 13 11:34:07 1992  Brian Fox  (bfox@cubit)
        * readline.c: (rl_variable_bind) New variable "meta-flag" if "on"
        means force the use of the 8th bit as Meta bit.  Internal variable
        is called meta_flag.
```

That happens to be the way it is interpreted with [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) and [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html).  A *few* terminals provided for making this feature optional (that aspect was not widespread. Most of the terminals you will encounter use hardcoded behavior (and not very interesting).  The [terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual page documents these terminal capabilities:

```
   has_meta_key              km     km   Has a meta key
                                         (i.e., sets 8th-bit)
   meta_off                  rmm    mo   turn off meta mode
   meta_on                   smm    mm   turn on meta mode
                                         (8th-bit on)
```

and explains the feature:

> If the terminal has a "meta key" which  acts  as  a  shift
>   key,  setting  the  8th  bit of any character transmitted,
>   this fact can be indicated with `km`.   Otherwise,  software
>   will assume that the 8th bit is parity and it will usually
>   be cleared.  If strings exist to turn this "meta mode"  on
>   and off, they can be given as `smm` and `rmm`.

A different feature, prefixing an escape character in response to the `Alt` key was incorporated into some terminal emulators.  Bash (actually the `readline` library) documents that usage in its [changelog](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/ChangeLog) from 2004:

```
lib/readline/callback.c            
        - use _rl_dispatch_callback and a chain of _rl_keyseq_contexts to
          simulate the recursion used to decode multicharacter key sequences
          (even things like ESC- as meta-prefix
```

Meta is a special case of a *modifier* key.  Like <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>, you press it at the same time as another key and expect to see something different from pressing the key by itself.  X provides for modifier keys by assigning a bit in the modifier value passed along in the X event for the key.  Key presses can be multiple X events; X provides functions for combining these events while retaining the modifiers.

X also defines symbols for each of the keys that might appear on your keyboard.  It provides for other values (such as Unicode) by special handling in the functions which combine events.

But "meta" is a special case.

X applications have no <kbd>meta</kbd> key, except by convention.  X does not have a definition for the meta key, or the meta modifier.  Conventionally, terminals look for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key and/or one of the modifiers known to [`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html), e.g., `mod2`.  The later *xkb* feature complicates things (but provides no improvement relative to this discussion) by providing another layer of information to find the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Convention of course can take you only so far, given that neither `xmodmap` nor `xkb` know anything in particular about *meta*.  xterm, for instance, is configurable, and not all users want to configure *meta* in the same way.  For instance, <kbd>Alt</kbd> may not be the intended meta-key, e.g., if it is used in the `translation` resource.  Another key may be the meta key, but users (particularly those using escape sequences in bash) may want an escape character sent when they press <kbd>Alt</kbd>.  But keep in mind that unless it is configured as a *modifier* none of that happens: xterm does not combine events by itself.

xterm has several resource settings (documented in the [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html)):

- `altIsNotMeta` and `altSendsEscape` (added in [2007](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_225)).
- `eightBitInput` since [2006](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_216) corresponds to the original sense of meta mode, and there is an escape sequence defined for this which provides the `smm` and `rmm` (set/remove meta-mode) terminal capabilities.
- `eightBitInput` was modified in [2003](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_183) to take UTF-8 into account by shifting the decoded Unicode values by 128 rather than the raw input bytes.
- `metaSendsEscape` dates from [1999](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_122)
- `eightBitInput` is much older than `metaSendsEscape`.  That has implemented a choice between *meta* mode (adding the eighth bit) or prefixing a key with <kbd>escape</kbd> since X11R4 (1989). But the feature was determined at startup: it was checked during initialization to determine whether the input was set to permit 8 bits or only 7.  After that, it did not change.

Some people equate the two (*8th-bit* and escape-prefix), referring to the latter as *meta* mode.  Depending on your point of view on the matter, the `eightBitInput` resource setting of xterm is part of the solution to getting a workable meta-key.

Further reading:

- [Alt-keys do not work in bash](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bash_meta_mode)