# The key codes for Caps Lock, Shift, Left Control and FN key?

Tags: vim, keyboard, tmux

Can somebody please provide the key codes for these keys:

- Caps Lock
- Left Shift
- Left Control
- Option key
- FN

The key code I'm talking about is something along the lines of `\<Esc>[200~`, although I have no idea what that outputs. :P

Thanks! I need this for remapping some keys in Vim, tmux etc.

Comment: `showkey` can probably tell you that

Comment: @charlesbridge OK, do you have an example of how you would use `showkey`? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

These keys are not sent to terminals. Only printable characters, function keys, and combinations of these keys with modifiers are sent to terminal applications (most function keys are sent in the form of escape sequences beginning with ESC `[`). Modifier keys (like <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc.) are visible to GUI applications, but not to terminal applications. You won't be able to detect a press of these keys in vim or tmux. See [What is bash's meta key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28993/what-is-bashs-meta-key/29077#29077) for more background.

With the <kbd>Fn</kbd> on many laptops, it's even worse: this key is handled by the BIOS and not even visible to the operating system.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thanks for your answer, will see if I can find a way to do this then. :)

Comment: It is not "handled by the BIOS".  [The Fn key is local.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/fn-key-is-local.html)

Comment: @JdeBP Yes, yes, I know that technically it's not “BIOS”. It's firmware (or even possibly hardware depending on the model). The point is that it's not under the OS's control. In the PC world, “BIOS” is usually synonymous with “stuff that runs outside of the OS's control”, often even including firmware running on chips other than the main CPU.

Comment: No, The microprocessor on the keyboard itself is *not* what "BIOS" means in the PC world, which refers to a specific thing, the old ROM firmware.

Answer (score 0):

`showkey` will dump out the code for any key you press.  You probably want `showkey -s` (although no options works well, too).  I pressed <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (the 0x9a is <kbd>ENTER</kbd> coming back up):

```
$showkey -s
kb mode was in UNICODE
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)
0x9a
0x2a 0xaa
```

Like the warning says, don't try it under xterm (or any X program).  It needs a real tty to read from.

Comment: Although that outputs it in a hexadecimal code, right? Would it work if it outputs like that? I need it for stuff like `t_SI` and stuff like that in Vim. Would that work?