# Why does delete work but not arrow keys in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard, arrow-keys

In a linux terminal I use "cat > file.txt" to make a file one line at a time.

What I find is that per-line the delete key works but the arrow keys insert escape codes rather than moving left and right in the line.

Why is this? Is there a reason that the terminals basic action cannot do left and right arrow keys? I know there are things like GNU readline which do it but my question is not about those.

Comment: Same reason as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103608/is-there-any-reason-why-i-get-a-when-i-press-up-arrow-at-the-console-login-sc

Comment: Because arrow keys are mapped to escape sequences, while the delete key is not (exercise: find out what it is mapped to. `man stty` may be interesting.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the line editing capabilities of the terminal driver are quite primitive and do **not** include things like moving the insertion point left and right.

What they do include:

- deleting the last char (`VERASE` / `erase`, BackSpace)
- deleting the last word (`VWERASE` / `werase`, Control-W)
- deleting the whole line (`VKILL` / `kill`, Control-U)

They're also not able to bind multiple key sequences (as the escapes sent by the left- and right-arrow keys usually are) to its special actions.

And of course, `VERASE` and `VWERASE` are not Unicode-aware; Linux has a perfunctory `IUTF8` flag (which works with simple data and is better than nothing), but it doesn't know about zero-width modifiers, directional marks, etc.

Look into the `stty(1)` and `termios(3)` manpages for more details.