# How to set Readline key bindings using ALT (Meta) or some other control key as prefix instead of `\C-` and `\e`?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, readline, macos

I can only find examples of setting Readline key bindings using Control (`\C-`) or Escape (`\e`) as prefixes.

In my case, on macOS, the `\C-` space is completely filled up by default key bindings, and the `\e` space is not practical on a Macbook with a touchbar.

Entering `"\M-f": kill-word` in `~/.inputrc` results in:

```
bind -P | grep -F "\M-"
kill-word can be found on "\e[3;5~" "\ed".
```

But `kill-word` cannot be executed using either of `Option`, `Command`, or `fn` as prefixes - Readline ignores it.

Is this issue specific to macOS, and how can I solve it?

Furthermore, how can I control the "timeout" that should occur before a key binding, that is a prefix of a longer key binding, is executed?

@added (@laktak): `bind '"^[f": kill-word'` doesn't work, but instead results in `ƒ` on the terminal:
[image]

Comment: Does using something other than `f` work? Since (at least on my Linux) `\M-f` is already bound to `forward-word`, perhaps that's causing a conflict.

Comment: Not in my case, `bind -q forward-word` results in `forward-word can be invoked via "\e[1;3C", "\e[1;5C", "\ef".`

Comment: Do you know if Readline only allows `\e` and `\C` as special prefixes?

Comment: Well yes, `\ef` is `M-f`. Does it work if you use another letter?

Comment: What do you mean by another letter? The `\ef` is only invoked, if I press the Escape key on the touchbar. Do you know if it's possible to map Option to Escape? And do you know how to control the "timeout", I mention :) ?

Comment: I mean not `f`. Use Meta and another letter, one that isn't already used anywhere. One of those returned by `for i in {a..z} {A..Z}; do bind -P | grep -q "\"\\\e$i" || echo $i; done`.

Comment: You should really configure your terminal emulator to do the equivalent of xtem's `*VT100.metaSendsEscape: true`, and then bind your keys as `"\ef"` instead of `"\M-f"`. See my comments [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535538/308316)

Comment: @mosvy, I would love to use `\e`, but it's a pain to press Escape on a Macbook with touchbar.

Comment: Your terminal emulator should send an `Escape`, `f` to the program inside the terminal when you press Option + F or whatever. Or it can be configured to do that.

Comment: @mosvy - thanks. I will try that. Do you also know how to control the "timeout" before Readline executes a key binding that's a prefix of another key binding?

Comment: `set keyseq-timeout 10`

Comment: ... in your `~/.inputrc`. or directly in bash with `bind 'set keyseq-timeout 10'`

Comment: @mosvy, thanks, but your comments doesn't seem to work for macOS. The terminal still prints "ƒ", when pressing Option+f.

Comment: I don't have a MacOS, but your terminal certainly has an option to send `escape, f` when pressing Option+F. Or if it doesn't, use another terminal or just `bind '"ƒ": ...` to whatever your want.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy! - it works by setting `bind '"ƒ": kill-word'`. But `bind -q kill-word` lists it as `"?\222"`. How can I see that `ƒ` corresponds to `"?\222"`?

Comment: you use `bind -q kill-word | od -c`, see that the '?' before `\222` is octal 306, then `printf "\306\222\n"` will tell you that it really is `ƒ` (yes, this is another bash/readline bug).

Comment: if you remove the [`XXX` "experimental code"](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/bind.c?id=d894cfd104086ddf68c286e67a5fb2e02eb43b7b#n2490) which still assumes latin1 instead of multibyte/utf-8 and recompile bash, the binding will be printed as `"ƒ"` instead of `"<FROG>\222"`. You should submit a bug report.

Comment: @mosvy, is it also possible to go get `\306\222` from the `ƒ` (the other direction)?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, but you can try `echo ƒ | perl -pe 's/(.)/sprintf"\\%03o",ord$1/ge'`

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, you just need to tell Terminal.app to use the "Option" key as "Meta" instead. Just go to the preferences for Terminal (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>), then *Profiles*, then the *Keyboard* tab for your default profile and check "Use Option as Meta key."

[image: Screenshot of Terminal.app "Profiles" → "Keyboard" settings]

Otherwise, you're getting the default macOS behavior (in most keymaps) where Option + key produces special characters, just like <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> yields the [small letter "f" with hook](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0192/index.htm) from your screenshot (complete reference [here](https://www.webnots.com/option-or-alt-key-shortcuts-to-insert-symbols-in-mac-os-x/)).

In [iTerm 2](https://www.iterm2.com/), I believe the left Option key already does the sensible thing by default, but just in case, here's how to change that:

[image: iTerm 2 Option key behavior]

As far as remapping Option to Escape, if that's a thing you still wanted to do, that can be accomplished from the Keyboard prefpane in System Preferences, by clicking the "Modifier Keys…" button near the bottom of the window.

[image: macOS System Settings Keyboard prefpane]

Then remap it to whatever you please (from the available choices):

[image: Remapping modifier keys in the macOS Keyboard prefpane]

I hit up this preference pane in about the first five minutes of using a new Mac, just so I can remap Caps Lock to Control, since the Control key on a Mac keyboard is in an awkward spot.

Comment: I should add that the option key in macOS is faaaaar too useful to be remapping to something else. As an experiment, switch to Finder and open any menu (even the Ctrl+click / right-click context menu) and watch what happens when you press and release the "Option" key.

Answer (score 2):

The utility would be:

```
showkey (1)          - examine the codes sent by the keyboard
```

but this seems to be missing on mac-os...here it is "Key Codes"...?

Or you type ctrl-V (qouted insert) and then some special key. In bash, this prints `^[OP` in xterm and `^[[[A` in the console for the F1 key.

The readline variable:

```
keyseq-timeout (500)
```

is the timeout to use for a half-finished sequence.

Underneath this, there must be a sort of keymap file, where the keys get translated to symbols. This is from `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/mac/` on linux:

```
keycode 51 = Delete  Remove
        alt keycode 51 = Meta_Delete
        shift alt keycode 51 = Meta_Delete
        control keycode  51 = Remove
keycode 53 = Escape
        alt keycode 53 = Meta_Escape
        shift alt keycode 53 = Meta_Escape
keycode  54 = Control
keycode  55 = Alt         # Command/Apple key
keycode  56 = Shift
keycode  57 = Caps_Lock
keycode  58 = AltGr       # Alt/Option key
```

You see the flexibilty! The Meta-Delete symbol could become kill-word...

---

> bind '"^[f": kill-word

This `^[` must be a `\e`,  or a ctrl-V, then Escape: one byte, not circumflex plus bracket.

---

It is like saying: ^C means control-C, not a Shift-6 and then a Shift-c...in the shell (bash) or in vim when I type ctrl-v and then Esc I get `^[`, but it is just one character when you step back over it. Together with these meta-flag options in readline it can get complicated...I just illustrate the whole chain:

keymap "default.map" (translates scancode and modifier to keysymbols)

```
keycode 105 = Left F150 F151
  string F150 = "\033[150"
  string F151 = "\033[151"
keycode 106 = Right F154 F155
  string F154 = "\033[154"
  string F155 = "\033[155"
```

The F150 and F151 after default "Left" mean shift- and control-left-arrow. In a second step you can define a string, an escape sequence in this case. Here, `\e` did not work, but the octal 033 is ascii 27 is control-[ is Escape...this keymap is linux specific, but X Windows has a similar logic.

And in .inputrc:

```
"\e[150": backward-word 
"\e[151": shell-backward-word 
"\e[154": forward-word 
"\e[155": shell-forward-word
```

This works very nice in the linux console. In xterm under X Windows (Xorg): not at all: Xorg scans the keys itself.

```
backward-word can be invoked via "\e[150", "\e[1;2D", "\e[1;3D", "\eb".
```

The two in the middle with semicolon are VTxxx style modified left arrows. This was preconfigured, and also gets bound to `backward-word` automatically.

Comment: Thanks is `keyseq-timeout` in milliseconds? Do you see it in `man bash`, or where should I look? You're right, `showkey` is not available on macOS through `brew`. I cannot get you `Ctrl-V` trick to work in iTerm :(

Comment: What do you mean by "console"? Isn't `xterm` the same as the console?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "This ^[ must be a \e, or a ctrl-V, then Escape: one byte, not circumflex plus bracket."? Could I use `^[` instead of `\e`?

Comment: xterm is a (VT220) terminal emulator in a GUI. The linux console is the built-in virtual tty. The example (F1 key) in my answer shows one difference. xterm uses XKB from X Windows for key mapping, modifiers, kbd layout. I see now I have kill-word on \e[3;5~ like you --- this is Control-Delete for X. On the console the Delete and  arrow keys did not have any Shift- or Control mofifiers defined.

Comment: thanks. Off-topic: how do I identify whether I'm talking to the Linux console built-in virtual tty, or some other terminal emulator?

Comment: The $TERM variable is used for that. Vim has an option -T to override it. After "vim -T linux" in xterm (or "TERM=linux vim") the modified arrow doesn't work. In a xterm shell $TERM is "xterm", on a linux vt it is "linux" .  I understand xterm uses the terminfo "database" to map the XKB escape sequences to certain well-known functions. All this seems totally screwed up, but it just grew like that historically.  Wikipedia has good articles on how things evolved.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
bind '"^[f": kill-word'
```

Will define `Option+F` to invoke `kill-word`

Comment: Thanks, @laktak. How do I see that `^[f` means `Option`? Are there also symbols for e.g. `Command`? Also, do you know the answer to, how to control the "timeout" before Readline uses a key binding that's a prefix of another key binding?

Comment: your solution doesn't seem to work. `Option`+`f` results in `ƒ` in the terminal.

Comment: @Shuzheng press `Control`+`v` (at the prompt) and then type the key combination you want to use - this should show you the keycode for the bind.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use `Esc` and then hit the `d` button, with that you can simulate the same keybinding.

Same as pasting the last argument of the previous command (`M-.`) could be replaced by hitting `Esc` first and then `.`.

To help myself on my MacBooks starting with the Touch Bar versions I've remapped the `Caps Lock ⇪` with `⎋ Escape`

[image: Remapping Caps Lock]