# Zsh get terminfo keys with modifiers

Tags: zsh, terminfo

The Arch Linux Wiki page on Zsh has an example that gets key sequences from terminfo in it.

```
typeset -g -A key

key[Home]="${terminfo[khome]}"
key[End]="${terminfo[kend]}"
...
```

But how would I get ones with modifiers? Specifically Alt+j and Alt+k.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [zsh: Where is the \`key\` -> \`terminfo\` dictionary defined](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/378730)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ncurses` terminal database defines these (see [*How can I use shift- or control-modifiers?*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#modified_keys) in the `ncurses` FAQ).

Most of this it's based on work done for `xterm` (see [this page](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm-function-keys.html), for example).

Those are unique names (which `zsh` ignores, since they're not in its dictionary of predefined terminal names — see [Src/Modules/terminfo.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/Modules/terminfo.c)).  You'd have to make some shell assignment, say, to the output of `tput` to get the data into a variable.

<kbd>*Alt*</kbd> is typically not considered a *modifier* when applied to an ordinary key such as **`j`** or **`k`** in the `xterm`.

It has a mode ([modifyOtherKeys](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys)), which can tell it to send an escape sequence for different combinations (see [*How can my program distinguish control-I from tab?*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_modother) in the `xterm` FAQ).

In this case, `zsh` provides no help at all. Likewise, the terminal will not offer a table of the results (it deals with *special keys*).  A customized application would be needed.

You may have in mind the *meta* feature.  That does have a terminfo feature (**`smm`** to enable, **`rmm`** to disable).  However, most terminals (other than `xterm`) implement this differently from the [*documented*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Miscellaneous) behavior.  In `terminfo(5)`:

> If the terminal has a "meta key" which acts as a shift key, setting the
>   8th  bit  of any character transmitted, this fact can be indicated with
>   **`km`**.  Otherwise, software will assume that the 8th bit is parity and  it
>   will  usually be cleared.  If strings exist to turn this "meta mode" on
>   and off, they can be given as **`smm`** and **`rmm`**.

That's partly due to the backwards definition found in `bash` documentation (see [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266490/105132) for details).  But in any case, terminfo will not hold the information that tells your script what characters might be prefixed with <kbd>*Escape*</kbd>.